# Unable to save the data in two different table in golang using gorm

Tags: go, go-gorm, glide-golang, golang-migrate, go-sqlite3

[image]This is my code I'm not sure what went wrong the value which is in the user is getting updated in the user table properly but the address struct value is not storing the data in the address table

I want to save two users and address table with one struct association please kindly help me out. Please Help me out

```
db.Table(models.TABLE_USER).AutoMigrate(&models.User{})

db.Table(models.TABLE_USER_ADDRESS).AutoMigrate(&models.UserAddress{})

    type User struct {
    UserId          string        `json:"user_id" gorm:"column:user_id;not null; primarykey"`
    ClientID        string        `json:"cliend_id" gorm:"unique;type:varchar(100);not null"`
    SecertKey       string        `json:"secert_key" gorm:"unique;type:varchar(100);not null"`
    ClientSecretKey string        `json:"client_secert_key" gorm:"unique;type:varchar(100);not null"`
    FirstName       string        `json:"first_name" gorm:"varchar(100);not null"`
    LastName        string        `json:"last_name" gorm:"varchar(100);not null"`
    Address         []UserAddress `json:"address" gorm:"foreignKey:Id;references:UserId"`
    Email           string        `json:"email" gorm:"column:email;not null"`
    Phone           string        `json:"phone_no" gorm:"column:phone_no;not null"`
    CreatedDate     time.Time     `json:"created_date" gorm:"column:created_date"`
    UpdatedAt       time.Time     `json:"updated_at" gorm:"column:updated_at"`
}

type UserAddress struct {
    Id      string `json:"id" gorm:"column:id;not null;primaryKey"`
    Street1 string `json:"street1" gorm:"column:street1"`
    Street2 string `json:"street2" gorm:"column:street2"`
    City    string `json:"city" gorm:"column:city"`
    State   string `json:"state" gorm:"column:state"`
    Country string `json:"country" gorm:"column:country"`
}


func TestUserCreation(t *testing.T) {
    appconf := GetAppConfig()

    var user models.User

    user.UserId = "123456trds"
    user.ClientID = "1234321qws"
    user.Email = "abc@gmail.com"
    user.FirstName = "xyz"
    user.LastName = "acr"
    user.Phone = "9213430981"
    user.SecertKey = "09jfinbdskj"
    user.ClientSecretKey = "qwdcesdf"

    a := []models.UserAddress{}
    aj := append(a, models.UserAddress{
        Id:      "123456trds",
        City:    "Bengaluru",
        Street1: "Street1",
        Street2: "Street2",
        Country: "India",
    })

    user.Address = aj
    user.CreatedDate = time.Now()
    user.UpdatedAt = time.Now()

    fmt.Println(user)
    rs := repo.NewUserRepo(appconf)

    err := rs.Create(&user)

    if helpers.HasError(&err) {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

}


func (r *UserRepo) Create(user *models.User) errors.RestAPIError {
    db := r.DB
    fmt.Println("BD", user)
    if err := db.Table(models.TABLE_USER).Save(&user).Error; err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return errors.NewInternalServerError("Cannot save user in db")
    }
    return errors.NO_ERROR()
}
```

Comment: Your code works properly. What error do you get?

Comment: My Problem is The data which I'm trying to store in the address-table is not getting stored whereas my data in the user table is getting updated.

Comment: What is `models.TABLE_USER_ADDRESS` value? and what is your gorm version?

Comment: const TABLE_USER_ADDRESS = "user_address"
gorm version is  : github.com/jinzhu/gorm v1.9.16

Comment: No Luck Its not working!

Comment: I ran your code and it created `user_addresses` table instead of `user_address` :-?

Comment: As you can see in the above image when i ran the code it's creating user_address only but not sure why its not getting updated

Comment: try as db.Table(models.TABLE_USER).Save(user) not &user

Answer (score 0):

Use `Create` instead of `Save`.

And check out this article.

https://gorm.io/docs/associations.html#Auto-Create-x2F-Update